# Arrow keys inside Bash script produce weird letters

Tags: bash

I wrote a simple script to manage the containers inside my application, however, whenever I press the arrow keys, they produce something like `[[A` or other characters. How can I fix the issue?

Example command is `./service.sh app shell` which will open up the shell of my Laravel application inside Docker container.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#application=$(basename "$PWD")
application="plexmediamanager"

services=("app", "roadrunner", "scheduler", "frontend", "nginx", "redis", "database", "queue", "torrent", "jackett", "traefik")
actions=("start", "stop", "restart", "shell", "rebuild")

if [[ ! "${services[@]}" =~ "${1}" ]]; then
    echo "Unknown service: ${1}"
    printf -v servicesString "%s" "${services[@]}"
    echo "Available services: ${servicesString}"
    exit 0
fi

if [[ ! "${actions[@]}" =~ "${2}" ]]; then
    echo "Unknown action: ${2}"
    echo "Available actions: start|stop|restart|shell|rebuild"
    exit 0
fi

case "$2" in
    "start")
    docker-compose start $1
    ;;
    "stop")
    docker-compose stop $1
    ;;
    "restart")
    docker-compose restart $1
    ;;
    "shell")
    docker exec -it "${application}_${1}" /bin/sh
    ;;
    "rebuild")
    docker-compose stop $1
    docker-compose build $1
    docker-compose start $1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Why do you press the arrow keys?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your script. None of the commands in your script are accepting input, so the terminal is simply echoing your keystrokes, and you are seeing the escape sequences generated by your terminal when it sees the arrow key pressed.

Comment: @Cyrus in order to select the previous command i have entered

Comment: @chepner is there a way then to use the `shell` command and start the `docker exec` thing outside of the script so i can use the arrow keys for selection of previously entered commands?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/ Fix yellow and red bugs.

Comment: OK, that's because you are running `/bin/sh` in that case, which isn't using any kind of library to process its input. It sounds like you want to run some shell other than `/bin/sh` that provides command-line editing.

Comment: It sounds like you should be able to reproduce the problem just by running `docker exec -it "plexmediamanager_app" /bin/sh`, right? In any case, please make a [mre].

Comment: @chepner i am building an Open Source Project, so i cant really target any other shell, since i cannot be sure that person has it installed. Seems like there is no other way but to just type in all the commands by hand when i am inside the docker shell through my script. Than you for your help!

Comment: Are you providing the image for `docker exec` to use, or is that user selectable? If the former, provide any shell you want and run that. If the latter, it's the user's responsibility to know how to use the shell they selected by choosing a particular image.

Comment: Your script doesn't read any commands, nor it loops. It just runs some docker command based on command line arguments. After your script finishes you should be able to resume typing commands.

Comment: Why did you roll back @halfer's edits?

Comment: (Just a quick side note about editing in general - Stack Overflow has mutual editing build right into its DNA, and technical writing is preferred. Thus, if an experienced editor amends your question or answer post, in general it is a good idea to just leave the edit be. You can ping them by `@name` though, and FWIW I am very happy to justify my edits. I can generally supply links to relevant discussions on _Meta_).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, the shell you call in your `case` statement does not exit and has no functionality for scrolling through history as you are used to in bash.  You may be able to get that shell to exit using something like this:

```
docker exec -it "${application}_${1} && exit" /bin/sh
```

But that's just an untested guess.

Of course if you leave off the call to the other shell (and let the script run that command in the parent shell), you could keep your script awaiting new command input by allowing for user input via `read` and stowing that inside a `while` loop.

(Also, it should be noted that you are handing `exec` two user-supplied variables and that is not a good practice.  Avoid `exec`, generally.)